# Converting next.js project works in dev but module not found when running build output

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

I've followed various tutorials to try and get my existing app working with Typescript. It's now running fine when working in dev mode: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development ts-node-script ./server/index.js`

When I run `next build` it succeeds, but once I try to run `./server/index.js` I get the error: `code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',`

I also don't see any compiled version of the `.ts` file in `.next/` or something. The instructions [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/typescript) make it seem like `next build` just handles everything...

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs" // you can also override compilerOptions.  Only ts-node will use these overrides
    }
  }
}
```

next.config.js

```js
const { parsed: localEnv } = require("dotenv").config();

const webpack = require("webpack");
const apiKey = JSON.stringify(process.env.API_KEY);
const hostUrl = JSON.stringify(process.env.HOST);

module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    const env = { API_KEY: apiKey, HOST_URL: hostUrl };
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.DefinePlugin(env));

    // Add ESM support for .mjs files in webpack 4
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.mjs$/,
      include: /node_modules/,
      type: "javascript/auto",
    });

    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full error stack?

Answer (score 2):

You (past me) need to build the files with `tsc` as part of the existing build command.

If you run into issues with the files not being output (just an empty `dist` directory) you'll need a different `tsconfig.json` for production.

Then update your package.json scripts:

```json
  "build": "next build; tsc --project tsconfig.server.json",
  "start": "node start dist/index.js"
```

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noEmit": false
  },
  "include": ["server"]
}
```